# F# Xml Type Provider test if node exists

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers

This seems like it should be trivial. I'm parsing many XML files, some of which contain all of the expected nodes, some of which do not. I need to be able to test for the existence of a node. I am using the F# Xml Type Provider. This code does not work but it illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
#r "../../../bin/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Author = XmlProvider<"""<author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924"><height>10</height></author>""">
let sample = Author.Parse("""<author name="Karl Popper" born="1902" />""")
let containsHeight = sample.Height <> null // I want this to return false
```

Comment: @CoderDennis, I added the height element to the XmlProvider example data. This is what it wold look like in my code. I would parse an XML file which was similar to the example but did not contain all of the same nodes.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24524247/126014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML Type Provider works by inferring the type from the sample. You can provide more than one sample by using the optional `SampleIsList` argument:

```
open FSharp.Data

type Author = XmlProvider<"""
<samples>
    <author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924">
        <height>10</height>
    </author>
    <author name="Karl Popper" born="1902" />
</samples>""", SampleIsList = true>
```

This enables you to load both `popper` and `feyerabend`:

```
let popper = Author.Parse("""<author name="Karl Popper" born="1902" />""")
let feyerabend = Author.Parse("""<author name="Paul Feyerabend" born="1924"><height>10</height></author>""")
```

You can now test whether or not the height is there:

```
> popper.Height.IsSome;;
val it : bool = false
> feyerabend.Height.IsSome;;
val it : bool = true
> feyerabend.Height |> Option.get;;
val it : int = 10
```

Comment: darn. and I did read documentation on XmlProvider before answering... apperently not thourough enough. thx for the lesson! please vote for deletion of my answer...

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm, I read the documentation as well and did not find this feature. That is what prompted me to ask this question.